# Grouping inside of a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, grouping

I am using a modified quantile regression function found in a scientific paper. (source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.04805.pdf)

I try to apply this particular methodology to my dataset, but I would like to perform this quantile regression based on a condition from my dataset. This means that I want to implement something similar to a group_by condition as found here:

```
qr_models = data %>%
  group_by(latitude) %>%
  do(model = rq(julian_day~year, tau = 1:99/100, method = "fn", data= .))
```

The way it is coded in the paper is the following and the loop is where I would like to add the group_by:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  alpha = i/(n+1)
  alphas[i] = alpha
  betas <- smrq(X,y,tau=alpha) 
  vals0[i] <- sum(y<(X %*% betas))
}
```

where n is `n <- 99` (the quantile resolution chosen); `vals0 <- rep(0,n)` and `alphas <- rep(0,n)`. I tend to avoid using loops in R so I am a bit lost on how to do it.

Just in case it is needed to understand, the `smrq()` function is the one that is described in the paper mentioned previously, and is coded like this:

```
smrq <- function(X, y, tau){
  p = ncol(X)
  op.result <- optim(rep(0, p),
                     fn = minimize.logcosh,
                     method = 'BFGS',
                     X = X,
                     y = y,
                     tau = tau)
  beta <- op.result$par
  return (beta)
}
```

where X is the explanatory variable matrix and y the response variable.

I hope it is clear enough, if more details are needed I will be happy to update my post. Many thanks for the precious help.

Comment: Actually, since the `for` loop is updating a vector, authors could have used `sapply` or `vapply`!

Comment: thanks for answering, so you mean that it is possible to update it this way without altering the functioning and with adding my group_by condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider encapsulating the author's entire processing in a user-defined method that receives data (`swiss` from authors) as input parameter along with other variables including formula (`Fertility ~ .` from authors) and response column (`"Fertility"` from authors).

Then, pass data subsets with `group_by`. Also, the authors `for` loop can be refactored to a vectorized loop such as `sapply` or `vapply` since the return is a numeric vector.

**Generalized Functions**

```r
minimize.logcosh <- function(par, X, y, tau) {
    diff <- y-(X %*% par)
    check <- (tau-0.5)*diff+(0.5/0.7)*logcosh(0.7*diff)+0.4
    return(sum(check))
}

smrq <- function(X, y, tau){
    p <- ncol(X)
    op.result <- optim(
        rep(0, p),
        fn = minimize.logcosh,
        method = 'BFGS',
        X = X,
        y = y,
        tau = tau
    )
    beta <- op.result$par
    return(beta)
}

run_smrq <- function(data, fml, response) {
    x <- model.matrix(fml, data)[,-1]
    y <- data[[response]]
    X <- cbind(x, rep(1,nrow(x)))

    n <- 99
    betas <- sapply(1:n, function(i) smrq(X, y, tau=i/(n+1)))
    # betas <- vapply(1:n, function(i) smrq(X, y, tau=i/(n+1)), numeric(1))
    return(betas)        
}
```

**Callers**

Test authors' example

```r
swiss <- datasets::swiss
smrq_models <- run_smrq(data=swiss, fml=Fertility~., response="Fertility")
```

**`dplyr`** *(using [`group_map`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html))*

```r
smrq_models <- data %>%
  group_by(latitude) %>%
  group_map(~ run_smrq(data=., fml=julian_day~year, response="julian_day")
```

**`base`** *(using `by`, the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`)*

```r
smrq_models <- by(
   data, 
   data$latitude, 
   function(sub) run_smrq(data=sub, fml=julian_day~year, response="julian_day")
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the great answer. There is still a small issue in it, because I believe that `run_smrq <- function(data, fml, response) {
  x <- model.matrix(fml, data)[,-1]
  y <- data[[response]]
  X <- cbind(x, rep(1,nrow(x)))`
  was made by the authors in order to fit their dataset example swiss. I cannot yet manage to make it work with another dataset.

Comment: More precisely, I think the issue is in the x design: `x <- model.matrix(fml, data)[,-1] `

Comment: I think that an easy solution is to always put the response variable (flm) as a first column in the initial dataset

Comment: I was able to run everything, I accepted your answer :) many thanks again. Just one more precision please, I would like to plot the results of my models, to get a view of the intercept and the explanatory variable. How can I do that? I will edit my post to make the graphical output clear :)

Comment: Great to hear you adjusted for final solution and glad to help! For plotting, try returning a matrix or data frame of all needed vectors for plotting (borrowing from author's plot code): `cbind(alphas = (1:n)/(c(1:n)+1), betas = betas, vals=sum(y<(X %*% betas)))`. Then, plot either pairings with alphas (i.e., taus) as X axis.

Comment: ok great, just one thing, where do you fit this line in the code? because if I run it just at the end, it says `object 'betas' not found`

Comment: It will be the `return` object of `run_smrq()`. So instead of returning the single vector, *betas*, return this matrix (cbind of multiple vectors).

Comment: I have managed to do this, but the plot part is still strange to me, I have added the output to my post, it does not give a 2 windows plot with intercept and explanatory variable as I wish I had?

Comment: Honestly, I am not familiar with the smrq model. And this plotting need may have to be a new question. Are you plotting the full data or group by subsets? Plotting *betas* or *values*? For values, try the matrix multiplication of just `X %*% betas` -not sum of logicals like authors do.

Comment: Ok sure thanks a lot :) I did open a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989723/plotting-models-issued-from-a-modified-quantile-regression-function  / and I am plotting group by group (the regression should be made for every latitude). I will try your last idea :)